# Is the level size impacting the results of regression model?

Tags: model, statistics, regression, categorical-data, multi-level

I am fitting a regression model with two independent categorical variable and one numeric response variable. I have two levels in variable Category, A and B; three levels in variable Color, Red, Orange and Yellow. But the size of these levels vary a lot. I print out an example here:

```
Category Color Price
    A   R   12
    A   R   43
    A   Y   32
    A   Y   31
    A   R   21
    A   Y   56
    A   Y   34
    A   Y   23
    A   R   12
    A   R   6
    A   R   43
    B   Y   32
    B   R   12
    B   R   26
    B   O   15
    B   R   27
    B   R   14
    B   O   13
    B   R   37
    B   O   15
    B   O   47
    B   R   25
```

Category A has no Orange and Category B only has 1 Yellow. Is that fine to fit in a regression model to get a conclusion of how much price difference between Category and Colors?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any numeric feature variable, then it doesn't make much sense to build up a regression model. You can just use the means in each category. For instance, using pandas:

```
pd.pivot_table(df,columns=['Category','Color'],aggfunc=np.mean)

       Category  Color
Price  A         R        22.833333
                 Y        35.200000
       B         O        22.500000
                 R        23.500000
                 Y        32.000000
```

Comment: Thank you for comment. How about I have numeric variable? I just give an example above to discuss the level size. Actually I regression model with other variables in. Can you give me the answer for my question if I have 'Age' as how old is the item in my regression model?